# How to publish multi-project solution on Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azureportal

I have a solution with 2 projects (MVC and API) and 2 class libraries.

I have successfully published the MVC project to Azure (azurewebsites.net) through Visual Studio. However, when I try to publish the API project (which the MVC "frontend" uses to query the database), it breaks: meaning, the published MVC project - which was previously accessible - returns HTTP 404 instantly. The API project isn't available either.

I have tried the following:

- API has the same URI as the MVC +/path
- API has a different URI than the MVC (differentPath.azurewebsites.net)
- Use the same publish profile for both projects

Comment: Maybe I need an extra deployment slot?

Comment: Extra deployment slot for API seemed to solve *that* problem - both projects are accessible while deployed now.